# SQL - Split query results at comma for sorting into dropdown list

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a C# .NET MVC 5 project to get acquainted with MVC, and I'm having trouble deciding on the bet solution for taking the query results from a table table and splitting them at the comma.

I have a table called "Games" which has a column called, "Platforms." This column contains comma-separated values since games almost always are made for more than one platform nowadays. I want to take the content of the Platforms column and put it into a dropdown field in a form to allow users to search for games by platform. But I am not sure of the best way to split the query results so I don't have comma-separate values in the dropdown.

The function below is how I have things set up now in the GamesController file:

```
public ActionResult Index(string gamePlatform, string searchString)
{
    var PlatformLst = new List<string>();

    var PlatformQry = from d in db.Games
                   orderby d.Platform
                   select d.Platform;

    PlatformLst.AddRange(PlatformQry.Distinct());
    ViewBag.gamePlatform = new SelectList(PlatformLst);

    var games = from g in db.Games
                 select g;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        games = games.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(gamePlatform))
    {
        games = games.Where(x => x.Platform == gamePlatform);
    }

    return View(games);
}
```

And here is the form with the dropdown for searching (located in Index.cshtml):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<p>
    Title: @Html.TextBox("SearchString") <br />
    Platform: @Html.DropDownList("gamePlatform", "All")
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
</p>
}
```

This works but the dropdown field ends up being populated as such:

- Microsoft Windows, OS X, Linux, PlayStation 4
- Microsoft Windows, OS X, Xbox One
- Microsoft Windows, OS X, PlayStation 3, PlayStation 4, Xbox 360, Xbox
  One
- Microsoft Windows, Android, Xbox One
- and so on....

And so on. This isn't how I want the "search by platform" function to work. I would rather have it be one platform for dropdown field:

- Microsoft Windows
- OS X
- Linux
- PlayStation 3
- PlayStation 4
- Xbox 360
- Xbox One
- and so on...

I know that I can create a function or a stored procedure, or I can setup a function that returns XML. But I'm not sure which one is best for this situation.

Comment: Are you using a relational database (examples SQL Server, Oracle, postgres...)?

Comment: Your query is selecting all the `Platform` fields and adding them to a list 'as-is' which is why each selectlist item is a list.  This may not be what you want to hear but a much better way to do this is to refactor your database so there is a table called `Platforms`, and a mapping table which stores GameId against one or more PlatformIds. Then you could do 1 simple query to populate the `Platforms` selectlist.  Your current approach is a potental maintainability and scalability headache.

Comment: "This column contains comma-separated values since games almost always are made for more than one platform nowadays."    You (or somebody) needs to read some books on database design.  http://sbuweb.tcu.edu/bjones/20263/access/ac101_fundamentalsdb_design.pdf  Look for "First Normal Form" aka "1NF".  Please don't put comma seperated values in your database.  Please.....the world is begging you.

Comment: @granadaCoder I could have done without the sassy tone but I will look into this.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be to have a complete list of all platforms set aside in a Platforms database table or something like that.  However using what you have, you would have to loop through and split all of them out, then do a distinct at the end.

```
foreach (var platformString in PlatformQry)
{
    foreach (var platform in platformString .Split(','))
        PlatformList.Add(platform);
}
PlatformLst.Distinct();
```